# FreeBSD 11 Scrambled console

Tags: freebsd, console

I've had some previous experience with Linux in the past and have recently tried to install FreeBSD 11 on my Dell laptop.
The installation process was successful and I have done a full installation.

The problem occurs when I try to logon to the system after the installation.
The boot menu is shown in a worst resolution than the one during the installation and if I proceed to a normal boot the screen became scrambled, like a white noise in a TV. The only way to boot is escaping to loader prompt and issue the commands:

```
disable-module vesa
set kern.vty=vt
boot
```

However the vesa is already disabled in `/boot/default/loader.conf` (`vesa_load="NO"`) and there is no overriding in `/boot/loader.conf` and the vt is set in `/etc/rc.conf`.

My computer is a Dell Inspiron 15R 5537

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly the solution I was hopping for, but worked.

Booting through the loader prompt, as described in the question, I've managed to install de X Server (XOrg + KDE) and configure the system to boot to the graphic environment.

During the boot the screen is scrambled, but the graphic environment loads correctly. And, strange as it may seen, if I then change to the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+#) it looks nice too. It's important to note that just installing X is not enough. It only worked after I installed KDE and set to boot in graphic mode. Don't know if it would work with other WM's.

Don't trying to understand anymore I just thank to the Posix Lords In The Great Mainframe In The Cloud.

Comment: FreeBSD suffers from broken graphics card drivers. Many Intel APUs are not properly supported. I am not able to switch back to terminal since years with my i7 intel graphics. The graphics output freezes then and I need to reboot.